# Identifier is unidentified visual studio error "use"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost-asio, poco-libraries, game-development

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "funcs.h"
#include "request_handler.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include "reply.h"
#include "request.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "Server.h"
#include "Alliance.h"
#include "AllianceCore.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "City.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Tile.h"

 using namespace std;
 using namespace Poco::Data::Keywords;

{
    gserver->consoleLogger->information("Account doesn't exist");
    Session ses(gserver->serverpool->get());
    Statement select(ses);
    select << "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`= ?;", use(userName);
    select.execute();
    RecordSet rs(select);
}
```

vs2012 keeps sending out error c3861:

> 'use' : identifier not found

I have tried googling the answer but next to impossible the include the word "use" in the search. so I and bowing to the expertise of stackflow to try and help me out.  the "use" is located as such

```
use(username);
```

Is sends out the error for numerous line but it is always set the same "use(with whatever name or string or etc)"

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that supposed to be C++ or do you run a pre-parser against that code? Because I would be surprised that you really want a comma after that string. The select would most certainly use `<<` instead of the comma. That being said, I have no clue about your problem per se.

Comment: No, comma is fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
using namespace Poco::Data::Keywords
//...
select << "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`= ?;", use(userName);
```

or

```
select << "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`= ?;", Poco::Data::Keywords::use(userName);
```

Comment: you are correct in the namespace use but unlucky for me it opened more errors,     "list" : ambiguous symbol, syntax error :>, playeriter : undeclared identifier, etc

Comment: Narrow your code down to a copy-paste-compile and I will be able to help you. Otherwise, it's impossible to understand what you have going on.

Comment: From little that can be understood, it looks like you have declared a list which conflicts with std::list.